# Use Spinner and Adapter in Fragment

Tags: java, android, fragment, spinner, adapter

I when run the following code in Activity work But I when run the following code in Fragment doesn't work. I need to use this code in Fragment. I am a beginner. please help me.

**Code in Fragment :**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_filter, container, false);

    Spinner categorySpinner = (Spinner) container.findViewById(R.id.category_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> categoryAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getContext(), R.array.cat, R.layout.row_spinner);
    categorySpinner.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);

    return view;
}
```

I change `getContext()` to `getActivity()` or `this` or `this.getActivity` but doesn't work.

**Error (in `categorySpinner.setAdapter(categoryAdapter`):**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a null object reference
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Spinner categorySpinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.category_spinner);
```

Use view instead of container

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call a method on a null object because you aren't getting the right context for your fragment.

Change the following line:

```
Spinner categorySpinner = (Spinner) container.findViewById(R.id.category_spinner);
```

To:

```
Spinner categorySpinner = (Spinner) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.category_spinner);
```

Comment: dosen't work and show to me error : `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a null object reference`

Comment: Did you set the right activity context on your xml for that category_spinner?